# How to pass a parameter to h:commandLink after action is executed?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a commandLink labeled "SaveAndView". Once I click on this link, which is basically saving the data on the current page "a.xhtml", then generating an ID. Then its redirecting to page **"b.xhtml?id=|generatedID|"** to view the data. How can I pass the generated ID to this commandLink?

```
<h:commandLink action="#{mybean.save()}" 
               value="#{msg.saveAndView}" 
               target="_blank" includeViewParams="true">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{mybean.id}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

The sample code above generates an empty id parameter because the save() is not invoked yet

Comment: your explanation is not clear, please provide the `saveAndView()` implementation,and what is the exact problem, is the  `saveAndView()` method not invoked or it's onvoked but you can't get the `id`?!!

Comment: How do you redirect? Use `<f:viewParam>` inside `<f:metadata>` on the target page such as `<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" required="..." validator="..." converter="...".../>`.

Comment: The method saveAndView() is invoked without problems. The problem is that the #{bean.id} value is set after the method saveAndView is invoked. How can I update the link with my ID when its already rendered

Comment: If the `action` attribute is meant for implicit navigation then, just append `mybean.id` therein as a query-string parameter along with `includeViewParams="true"`, if needed.

Comment: The action "save()" is meant to save the data in the database. A unique ID is then generated after the data is saved. What I need to do is pass this ID in the URL as "b.xhtml?id=generatedID"

Comment: You don't need to set the `id` parameter to the server because **it doesn't exist** and it will be generated there. Then,in your `String saveAndView()` method, make sure to do a redirect to the proper view you want/need to display and add the generated id as query string parameter.

Comment: You then need to return that identifier from the service layer to the web layer after saving a row to the database. The id should be returned in JPA terms by `entity.getId()` - the method name may vary greatly (the last insert id, an auto-generated primary key) in the current database transaction on the service layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to *misunderstand* the basic workflow. In your case it is as follows:

1. User fills in a form with the data of a to-be-persisted entity;
2. User submits the form by clicking command link;
3. Action method is executed, within which:

   - New entity is persisted by calling `entityService.persist(entity);`;
   - An entity assigned an `id` after that method is executed (that is, the transaction executed therein has been committed);
   - You pass this id as a query parameter in return statement of your action method, `return "viewentity?id=" + entity.getId() + "&faces-redirect=true";` to redirect to the target view (assuming you have a numeric id that doesn't need to be encoded and you don't need to pass any other parameters);
4. On the target page use a `<f:viewParam name="id" ... />` to receive the `id` and use it to show the data you want.

So, to answer your question directly, you need to pass the generated `id` within your action method manually.

Comment: I think you should add a `"&amp;includeViewParams=true"` to the `return` of your method.